# How to change default path in pentaho-server 9.0.0.0.423?

Tags: tomcat, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I need to change the default path to pentaho-server
**Now:** http://localhost:8080/pentaho

**Should be like this**: http://localhost:8080/pentahotest

I tried to change server.properties (*pentaho-solutions/system/server.properties*), but it isn't work

```
fully-qualified-server-url=http://localhost:8080/pentahotest/
```

I also tried to do it with nginx but nothing was successful

Comment: The /pentaho part comes from the  tomcat webapps folder.   Changing the default path won't work because it's trying to find pentahotest under the tomcat/webapps folder and it's still called pentaho there.